# Podman unable to advertise port 53 even when the container has his own IP address

Tags: opensuse, podman

I am getting an error: `Error: cannot listen on the TCP port: listen tcp4 :53: bind: address already in use` When creating a container that gets his own IP address, this means that regardless of if there is some host program listening at port 53 the container should have no problems listening in the same port because his IP is not the same as the Host.

The command I am using to start the container is the following: `sudo podman run -d --network podnet -p 53:53 --name test-container test-image`

And inspecting the network `podnet` with `sudo podman inspect podnet` give the following:

```
[
     {
          "name": "podnet",
          "id": "<censored>",
          "driver": "macvlan",
          "network_interface": "bridge0",
          "created": "<censored>",
          "ipv6_enabled": false,
          "internal": false,
          "dns_enabled": false,
          "options": {
               "mode": "passthru"
          },
          "ipam_options": {
               "driver": "dhcp"
          }
     }
]
```

I am in a OpenSUSE Leap Micro machine.

Comment: You are passing the `-p` (`--publish`) option which attaches the port to your host machine (using all interfaces by default).  It sounds like your host machine already has port 53  in use.  Does it work if you remove the `-p` option?

Comment: @GracefulRestart It works but cannot test if the named service from bind9 is being public, because when running `dig google.com @localhost` in an exec session in the container it only gives me the error: `;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused`

Comment: Running the command within an `exec` session would have nothing to do with using `--publish`.  If it cannot run in the `exec` session, then it is not working.  You should post an example Dockerfile showing your problem to help troubleshoot this issue.